# Ask About The "default" Size of Vocabulary in Word2Vec in Deeplearning4j Library

Tags: java, word2vec, deeplearning4j

I am currently learning about this library: Word2Vec from Deeplearning4j ([Homepage](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/language-processing/word2vec), [Github](https://github.com/breandan/deep-learning-samples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecRawTextExample.java))

Following is the example usage of the method:

```
//build Word2Vec model
Word2Vec vec = new Word2Vec.Builder()
                .layerSize(100)
                .windowSize(5)
                .stopWords(stopList)
                .tokenizerFactory(t)
                .learningRate(0.025)
                .build();
```

I know that I can limit the vocabulary size with this method:

```
vec.limitVocabularySize(100) //limit the vocab size as 100
```

Above example is the command if I want to limit the vocab size into 100

**My question:** 
Could anyone inform me what is the *default* size of the vocab (i.e., if I do not set the limit)?

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no limit. That means it will add all words it finds to the vocabulary.

Also note, the examples you linked to are over 4 years old. I suggest you use the official examples: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples